# opencv - Best way to compare polygons and get their rotation

Tags: opencv

I have many many different polygons, they represent house shapes on the map. My goal is to compare all those shapes (which I store as point arrays) and find those similar in shape and size. Then, between those similar and shape and size, find their rotation difference.

Right now I rely on 'MatchShapes' function, but it does not care about sizes, so I am using 'MinAreaRect' firstly to get approximately same shapes. And still, as MatchShapes is rotation/scale/ invariant, I get somehow mixed results.

Maybe there is some other way you can recommend? As I have very clearly defined shapes - polygons.

For example, those polygons selected pass as similar with quite high value. There is no way to pick 'good one value' at all

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give some examples to get an impression of your data?

Comment: All my data is in NetTopologySuite format, IGeometry polygons, every polygon is just a number of double precision 2D points

Comment: i mean real examples of drawn (for better visualization) polygons which typically occur in your applicatin. Add information which polygons are grouped fine with matchShapes and which ones are grouped fine with minAreaRect and wich one aren't grouped fine. Currently YOU have a good impression of what kind of polygons typically appear ("As I have very clearly defined shapes") but we don't, so we can't really help...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Edited my first post, with image of my polygons. Those selected passed test, though if I set different treshhold, will never get everything work properly - tested many times

Comment: is there perspective foreshortening in your polygons or just in the visualization image? Can you mark all polygons, in a common color, that you assume to be similar?

Comment: just visualisation, they are flat 2d. I added other image to my post, showing some polygons I consider similar. They are not rotation invariant, i.e. I somehow need to detect similar, but rotated ones too, and get rotation angle